Using SQL magic in Jupyter, the output only displays the header without any rows

I am pretty sure there are rows in the table 'grade', and I have already installed IPython-SQL, DuckDB, and imported SQLAlchemy. But the output only displays the header without any rows.
I've tried restarting the kernel, but my problem wasn't solved.

Please read How do I ask a good question? and revise your post based on that guide. Especially pay close attention to the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' where it stresses in a bold bullet point, "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc." You had the code there as text and could have just pasted it in here as text that will be useable by others and importantly indexed by the SO system so questions are connected and findable by others.
